# Moment.js failed to valid time when passing date

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm reading values from an old csv file that I have. This file has a lot of wrong data, it should has only time values, but sometimes it has date values on it.
I'm trying to valid time with `moment.js`, but when I run this code:

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment('19/07/9130','hh:mm').isValid());
```

It returns `true`, I'm doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

1.
First of all, you are giving wrong format in moment function, you are passing data in `DD/MM/YYYY` format and defining format `hh:mm`. You should pass correct format.

2.
`19/07/9130` is valid date which have year `9130` and it's absolutely valid future year. If you want to restrict maximum year, you can use `isBefore` method

```
var mydate = moment('19/07/9130', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
var isValid = mydate.isValid() && mydate.isBefore('2050-01-01');
```

Comment: I think you don't understand, the value 19/07/1930 is wrong, because what I want is a time value. I'm reading an old csv file, that has a lot of wrong values. I want to validate if the value that I'm reading from csv is a valid time

Answer (score 0):

Reading more the `Moment.js` [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), I find a third parameter that make Moment use strict parsing.

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment('19/07/9130','hh:mm',true).isValid());
```

This works fine!